# How to get the corresponding value of the Max column

Tags: sql-server

What if I have this data? and I need to get the time of the latest time and the roundtrip of that latest time???

```
     Server| Site | RoundTrip |   Time   |
       A      AA      200       09:02:17
       A      AA      100       09:02:16
       A      AA      150       09:02:14
       B      AA      250       09:02:15
       B      AA      200       09:02:18
       B      AA      270       09:02:16
       C      AA      100       09:02:19
       C      AA      150       09:02:18
       C      AA      200       09:02:15
       D      AA      300       09:02:13
       D      AA      200       09:02:15
       D      AA      250       09:02:14
       A      BB      200       09:02:58
       A      BB      100       09:02:49
       A      BB      150       09:02:53
       B      BB      150       09:02:50
       B      BB      350       09:02:54
       B      BB      250       09:02:53
       C      BB      200       09:02:56
       C      BB      175       09:02:55
       C      BB      250       09:02:57
       D      BB      260       09:02:50
       D      BB      200       09:02:52
       D      BB      140       09:02:51
```

I need to get the latest time of all the server in different sites and their corresponding roundtrip. Because in my code I also get the max value of the roundtrip.

```
     Server| AA-Roundtrip | Time-AA  | BB-Roundtrip | Time-BB   |
       A         200        09:02:17       200        09:02:58
       B         200        09:02:18       350        09:02:54
       C         100        09:02:19       250        09:02:57
       D         200        09:02:15       200        09:02:52
```

Any one can help me?
Please..

Answer (score 1):

I think you `SELECT MAX(RoundTrip) GROUP BY (Server, Site)`. You can use [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to choose max value, like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT
         *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Server, Site ORDER BY RoundTrip DESC) AS RN
      FROM Your_Table
   ) AS A
   WHERE RN = 1 -- choose max value RoundTrip)

-- using CROSS APPLY
SELECT A.Site, A.[AA-RoundTrip], A.[AA-Time], B.[BB-RoundTrip], B.[BB-Time]
   FROM (
      SELECT Site, RoundTrip AS [AA-RoundTrip], Time AS [AA-Time]
      FROM CTE WHERE Server = AA) AS A
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT Site, RoundTrip AS [BB-RoundTrip], Time AS [BB-Time]
      FROM CTE WHERE Server = BB AND Site = A.Site) AS B

-- using INNER JOIN
   SELECT A.Site, A.[AA-RoundTrip], A.[AA-Time], B.[BB-RoundTrip], B.[BB-Time]
   FROM (
      SELECT Site, RoundTrip AS [AA-RoundTrip], Time AS [AA-Time]
      FROM CTE WHERE Server = AA) AS A
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT Site, RoundTrip AS [BB-RoundTrip], Time AS [BB-Time]
      FROM CTE WHERE Server = BB) AS B
     ON A.Site = B.Site
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this one

Comment: @nguyen this is not at all giving result and more over it got syntax errors

Comment: @Jonathan: your question is same? your sql you use?

Comment: I have executed your query with sample data in Sql 2012 environment and it got syntax errors @NguyễnHảiTriều

Answer (score 1):

I think something in that line will works fine:

```
SELECT  AA.SERVER, 
        AA.[AA-ROUNDTRIP],
        AA.[TIME-AA],
        BB.[BB-ROUNDTRIP],
        BB.[TIME-BB]        
FROM
(SELECT SERVER, 
        MAX(ROUNDTRIP)[AA-ROUNDTRIP],
        TIME[TIME-AA]
  FROM ANYTABLE
  WHERE SITE= 'AA'
  GROUP BY SERVER,TIME) AA

INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT SERVER , 
            MAX(ROUNDTRIP)[BB-ROUNDTRIP],
            TIME[TIME-BB]
    FROM ANYTABLE
    WHERE SITE= 'BB'
    GROUP BY SERVER,TIME) BB

ON AA.SERVER=BB.SERVER
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query uses `PARTITION` to calculate the maximum round trip per site and server and then uses `CASE` for figuring out the correct values.

```
select 
  Server,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Site ='AA' and [Time]=MaxRoundTrip Then RoundTrip else NULL end)  as [AA-Roundtrip],
  MAX(CASE WHEN Site='AA'  then MaxRoundTrip  else NULL end) as [Time-AA],
  MAX(CASE WHEN Site ='BB' and [Time]=MaxRoundTrip Then RoundTrip else NULL end)  as [BB-Roundtrip],
  MAX(CASE WHEN Site='BB'  then MaxRoundTrip  else NULL end) as [Time-BB]
from
(
  select *, MAX([Time]) Over(Partition by Server, Site) as maxroundtrip from t
) t
group by Server
```

**Working SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/007a0/5

Comment: Nah.. I try it with the database. but it also get the maximum value of the roundtrip.

Comment: @Elphrian I had initially misunderstood the problem and had done a max on round trip and not on time, the original fiddle for that case is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/007a0/5 Since then I have revised my answer. Please do check.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
WITH LEFT_PART AS (
SELECT 
        SERVER,
        AA_Roundtrip = MIN(Roundtrip)
    FROM 
        DATA
    WHERE
        Site = 'AA'
    GROUP BY Server
),RIGHT_PART AS (
SELECT 
        SERVER,
        BB_Roundtrip = MIN(Roundtrip)
    FROM 
        DATA
    WHERE
        Site = 'BB'
    GROUP BY Server
)
SELECT 
        LP.Server
        ,AA_Roundtrip
        ,Time_AA = (
            SELECT TOP(1) time FROM DATA D
                WHERE
                    D.Server = LP.Server
                    AND D.Roundtrip = LP.AA_Roundtrip
                ORDER BY
                    D.time DESC
        ) 
        ,BB_Roundtrip
        ,Time_BB = (
            SELECT TOP(1) time FROM DATA D
                WHERE
                    D.Server = LP.Server
                    AND D.Roundtrip = RP.BB_Roundtrip
                ORDER BY
                    D.time  DESC    
        )
    FROM 
        LEFT_PART LP 
        JOIN RIGHT_PART RP ON LP.Server = RP.Server
```